# singleton-registry pattern and object-interaction with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, singleton

My problem may be very specific i think. I already tryed to find some info about it, have viewed tons of sites, but with no success. And i'm a newbee in OO-php. I will try to explain issue without samples of code:

So, i have develop object-oriented php application. My Registry class implement singeltone pattern (have only one instance in whole app) and store objects that must be accessible in any part of application. At this moment i need to call JQuery AJAX to interact with user without page reloading. But calling php script via AJAX give me another instance of my Registry class (when i try to use registry in called php-file), this instance certainly empty (have no objects in array). I think this happened because AJAX calls works in different threads (may be i'm mistake). Anyway - is where some way to rich needed functionality using registry-pattern ? Or may be there is another ways to achieve it? I know that i can make my classes static, and use objects statically, but unfortunately i can't do it. I also know about global vars - it's no my way... Any help, please!

Comment: Erm, unless you have a you have a continious running PHP application (which is rare, seldomly used, and usually more suited to other languages), isn't it so that on every _normal_ (non-ajax) request you have to rebuild or at least recreate your Registry object? So, that would be the way to go with the ajax requests too. How are you currently storing your Registry singleton, how do you recreate it on the next request, and what is different about the ajax calls?

Comment: For example: $instance = Application_Models_Registry::getInstance();
$instance->set('mySubjectList', $subjectList); Registry class is a just a standart singleton store-class. Then in any part of app, i can create instance of Registry again and have access to $subjectList calling get method

Comment: Those singletons don't survive until the next request unless you store them somewhere (cache/sessions).

Answer (score 1):

So every single request to a PHP application is handled by a separate process on the server.  No memory/data is shared across requests.  That being the case, the Ajax request to the PHP script will not have access to your other request's info.

In order to handle this, You'll need to keep state of the data you're trying to store in some other way.  Store it in the DB, Sessions, etc.

So say you have a "singleton-ish" list of objects that are items available in a store, the number in stock and their meta data.

in pseudo code:

```
$inventory = array(
       "cars" => array(SomeCarObject, AnotherCarObject), 
       "trucks" => array(SomeTruckObject, AnotherTruckObject)
    );
```

Because this is not kept in shared memory accross requests, every time you need to asynchronously operate on  on this list, you'll need to fetch it (from where ever you're keeping state of it), modify it, then save it and respond appropriately.

Your flow might look something like this:

client request `$inventory` => server fetches state of `$inventory`, does stuff, resaves => sends `$inventory` back to client.

You will likely need to add a locking mechanism to the DB to indicate that another process is using it but that's something you'd need to exercise caution with because it can cause other requests to wait for something that is modifying your data to finish before they can finish.  You do not want to introduce a race condition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: Ok, it's clear and was expected. And i understand that i can store my data-objects in some way, like json.... But what if i need access to non-serialized class, for example - i store objects in a collection, collection class have some methods to manipulate objects, and i need to apply these methods to collection async., so i need a collection object with all methods and not only data. I fill that i misunderstand something...

Comment: If you have a collection, you have to serialize the collection when you need to save it and deserialize it when you need it.  I'll add the notes to the answer for further explanation